# The same JSON query is slower with Gin index

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with one column as jsonb, I am trying to use GIN index to make the queries faster. however after added the index, queries are slower compare to before. did I miss anything?

1.table structure

```
pg_tech=# \d+ financial_news 
                              Table "public.financial_news"
 Column | Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+-------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 news   | jsonb |           |          |         | extended |              | 
Access method: heap
```

2. before add index

```
pg_tech=# explain analyze select * from financial_news where news @> '{"language": "english"}';
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on financial_news  (cost=0.00..30082.24 rows=273 width=725) (actual time=0.107..2553.104 rows=273459 loops=1)
   Filter: (news @> '{"language": "english"}'::jsonb)
 Planning Time: 0.178 ms
 Execution Time: 2561.911 ms
(4 rows)
```

3. add GIN index to JSONB column

```
pg_tech=# create index idx_json_news on financial_news using gin(news);
```

4. analyze the same query

```
pg_tech=# explain analyze select * from financial_news where news @> '{"language": "english"}';
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on financial_news  (cost=46.12..1055.12 rows=273 width=725) (actual time=29.058..2609.573 rows=273459 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (news @> '{"language": "english"}'::jsonb)
   Heap Blocks: exact=26664
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_json_news  (cost=0.00..46.05 rows=273 width=0) (actual time=26.693..26.693 rows=273459 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (news @> '{"language": "english"}'::jsonb)
 Planning Time: 0.248 ms
 Execution Time: 2617.969 ms
(7 rows)
```

Comment: If you are fetching most of the table, using an index isn't going to be very useful.  It isn't like it made it 10 times slower.  It is 2% slower, which I doubt is even reliably reproducible.

Comment: You should do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, and make sure track_io_timing is turned on first.  Also, the row estimates are way off , make sure the table was vacuumed and analyzed recently.